# xmpp framework can i used in xcode 8

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode8

what xmpp framework can i used in xcode 8? i try to install `pod "xmpp-messanger-ios"`in swift. but when i built my project was failed because there's many error in file oneChat.swift, i guess it because the project detected as swift 3 in xcode 8. i've change value of swift legacy in build setting to YES. but still not effect, whats wrong?

is there any other framework?

note: my project run on iOS 10

error log when compile kXMPP.swift

> Showing All Messages
>   CompileSwift normal x86_64 /Users/Unitedtronik/Desktop/macProject/swift3v2/Pods/xmpp-messenger-ios/Pod/Classes/kXMPP.swift
>       cd /Users/Unitedtronik/Desktop/macProject/swift3v2/Pods
>       /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/Swift_2.3.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift -frontend -c -primary-file /Users/Unitedtronik/Desktop/macProject/swift3v2/Pods/xmpp-messenger-ios/Pod/Classes/kXMPP.swift /Users/Unitedtronik/Desktop/macProject/swift3v2/Pods/xmpp-messenger-ios/Pod/Classes/OneChat.swift /Users/Unitedtronik/Desktop/macProject/swift3v2/Pods/xmpp-messenger-ios/Pod/Classes/OneChats.swift /Users/Unitedtronik/Desktop/macProject/swift3v2/Pods/xmpp-messenger-ios/Pod/Classes/OneLastActivity.swift /Users/Unitedtronik/Desktop/macProject/swift3v2/Pods/xmpp-messenger-ios/Pod/Classes/OneMessage.swift /Users/Unitedtronik/Desktop/macProject/swift3v2/Pods/xmpp-messenger-ios/Pod/Classes/OnePresence.swift /Users/Unitedtronik/Desktop/macProject/swift3v2/Pods/xmpp-messenger-ios/Pod/Classes/OneRoom.swift /Users/Unitedtronik/Desktop/macProject/swift3v2/Pods/xmpp-messenger-ios/Pod/Classes/OneRoster.swift -target x86_64-apple-ios8.0 -enable-objc-interop -sdk /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator10.0.sdk -I /Users/Unitedtronik/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/swift3-cmzgbcrjozvlxvdgywzgbvuzmnqx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/xmpp-messenger-ios -F /Users/Unitedtronik/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/swift3-cmzgbcrjozvlxvdgywzgbvuzmnqx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/xmpp-messenger-ios -F /Users/Unitedtronik/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/swift3-cmzgbcrjozvlxvdgywzgbvuzmnqx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/CocoaAsyncSocket -F /Users/Unitedtronik/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/swift3-cmzgbcrjozvlxvdgywzgbvuzmnqx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/CocoaLumberjack -F /Users/Unitedtronik/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/swift3-cmzgbcrjozvlxvdgywzgbvuzmnqx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FMDB -F /Users/Unitedtronik/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/swift3-cmzgbcrjozvlxvdgywzgbvuzmnqx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/JSQMessagesViewController -F /Users/Unitedtronik/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/swift3-cmzgbcrjozvlxvdgywzgbvuzmnqx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/JSQSystemSoundPlayer -F /Users/Unitedtronik/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/swift3-cmzgbcrjozvlxvdgywzgbvuzmnqx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/KissXML -F /Users/Unitedtronik/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/swift3-cmzgbcrjozvlxvdgywzgbvuzmnqx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/XMPPFramework -enable-testing -g -import-underlying-module -module-cache-path /Users/Unitedtronik/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache -D COCOAPODS -serialize-debugging-options -Xcc -I/Users/Unitedtronik/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/swift3-cmzgbcrjozvlxvdgywzgbvuzmnqx/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/xmpp-messenger-ios.build/swift-overrides.hmap -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/Unitedtronik/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/swift3-cmzgbcrjozvlxvdgywzgbvuzmnqx/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/xmpp-messenger-ios.build/xmpp_messenger_ios-generated-files.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/Unitedtronik/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/swift3-cmzgbcrjozvlxvdgywzgbvuzmnqx/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/xmpp-messenger-ios.build/xmpp_messenger_ios-own-target-headers.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/Unitedtronik/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/swift3-cmzgbcrjozvlxvdgywzgbvuzmnqx/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/xmpp-messenger-ios.build/xmpp_messenger_ios-all-non-framework-target-headers.hmap -Xcc -ivfsoverlay -Xcc /Users/Unitedtronik/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/swift3-cmzgbcrjozvlxvdgywzgbvuzmnqx/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/all-product-headers.yaml -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/Unitedtronik/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/swift3-cmzgbcrjozvlxvdgywzgbvuzmnqx/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/xmpp-messenger-ios.build/xmpp_messenger_ios-project-headers.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/Unitedtronik/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/swift3-cmzgbcrjozvlxvdgywzgbvuzmnqx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/xmpp-messenger-ios/include -Xcc -I/Users/Unitedtronik/Desktop/macProject/swift3v2/Pods/Headers/Private -Xcc -I/Users/Unitedtronik/Desktop/macProject/swift3v2/Pods/Headers/Public -Xcc -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator10.0.sdk/usr/include/libxml2 -Xcc -I/Users/Unitedtronik/Desktop/macProject/swift3v2/Pods/XMPPFramework/module -Xcc -I/Users/Unitedtronik/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/swift3-cmzgbcrjozvlxvdgywzgbvuzmnqx/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/xmpp-messenger-ios.build/DerivedSources/x86_64 -Xcc -I/Users/Unitedtronik/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/swift3-cmzgbcrjozvlxvdgywzgbvuzmnqx/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/xmpp-messenger-ios.build/DerivedSources -Xcc -DPOD_CONFIGURATION_DEBUG=1 -Xcc -DDEBUG=1 -Xcc -DCOCOAPODS=1 -Xcc -ivfsoverlay -Xcc /Users/Unitedtronik/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/swift3-cmzgbcrjozvlxvdgywzgbvuzmnqx/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/xmpp-messenger-ios.build/unextended-module-overlay.yaml -Xcc -working-directory/Users/Unitedtronik/Desktop/macProject/swift3v2/Pods -emit-module-doc-path /Users/Unitedtronik/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/swift3-cmzgbcrjozvlxvdgywzgbvuzmnqx/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/xmpp-messenger-ios.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/kXMPP~partial.swiftdoc -Onone -module-name xmpp_messenger_ios -emit-module-path /Users/Unitedtronik/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/swift3-cmzgbcrjozvlxvdgywzgbvuzmnqx/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/xmpp-messenger-ios.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/kXMPP~partial.swiftmodule -serialize-diagnostics-path /Users/Unitedtronik/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/swift3-cmzgbcrjozvlxvdgywzgbvuzmnqx/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/xmpp-messenger-ios.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/kXMPP.dia -emit-dependencies-path /Users/Unitedtronik/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/swift3-cmzgbcrjozvlxvdgywzgbvuzmnqx/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/xmpp-messenger-ios.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/kXMPP.d -emit-reference-dependencies-path /Users/Unitedtronik/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/swift3-cmzgbcrjozvlxvdgywzgbvuzmnqx/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/xmpp-messenger-ios.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/kXMPP.swiftdeps -o /Users/Unitedtronik/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/swift3-cmzgbcrjozvlxvdgywzgbvuzmnqx/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/xmpp-messenger-ios.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/kXMPP.o
>   /Users/Unitedtronik/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/swift3-cmzgbcrjozvlxvdgywzgbvuzmnqx/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/xmpp-messenger-ios.build/unextended-module.modulemap:2:19: error: umbrella header 'xmpp-messenger-ios-umbrella.h' not found
>     umbrella header "xmpp-messenger-ios-umbrella.h"
>                     ^
>   :0: error: could not build Objective-C module 'xmpp_messenger_ios'

error log when compile OneChat.swift

> Showing All Messages
>   CompileSwift normal x86_64 /Users/Unitedtronik/Desktop/macProject/swift3v2/Pods/xmpp-messenger-ios/Pod/Classes/OneChat.swift
>       cd /Users/Unitedtronik/Desktop/macProject/swift3v2/Pods
>       /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/Swift_2.3.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift -frontend -c /Users/Unitedtronik/Desktop/macProject/swift3v2/Pods/xmpp-messenger-ios/Pod/Classes/kXMPP.swift -primary-file /Users/Unitedtronik/Desktop/macProject/swift3v2/Pods/xmpp-messenger-ios/Pod/Classes/OneChat.swift /Users/Unitedtronik/Desktop/macProject/swift3v2/Pods/xmpp-messenger-ios/Pod/Classes/OneChats.swift /Users/Unitedtronik/Desktop/macProject/swift3v2/Pods/xmpp-messenger-ios/Pod/Classes/OneLastActivity.swift /Users/Unitedtronik/Desktop/macProject/swift3v2/Pods/xmpp-messenger-ios/Pod/Classes/OneMessage.swift /Users/Unitedtronik/Desktop/macProject/swift3v2/Pods/xmpp-messenger-ios/Pod/Classes/OnePresence.swift /Users/Unitedtronik/Desktop/macProject/swift3v2/Pods/xmpp-messenger-ios/Pod/Classes/OneRoom.swift /Users/Unitedtronik/Desktop/macProject/swift3v2/Pods/xmpp-messenger-ios/Pod/Classes/OneRoster.swift -target x86_64-apple-ios8.0 -enable-objc-interop -sdk /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator10.0.sdk -I /Users/Unitedtronik/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/swift3-cmzgbcrjozvlxvdgywzgbvuzmnqx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/xmpp-messenger-ios -F /Users/Unitedtronik/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/swift3-cmzgbcrjozvlxvdgywzgbvuzmnqx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/xmpp-messenger-ios -F /Users/Unitedtronik/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/swift3-cmzgbcrjozvlxvdgywzgbvuzmnqx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/CocoaAsyncSocket -F /Users/Unitedtronik/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/swift3-cmzgbcrjozvlxvdgywzgbvuzmnqx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/CocoaLumberjack -F /Users/Unitedtronik/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/swift3-cmzgbcrjozvlxvdgywzgbvuzmnqx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FMDB -F /Users/Unitedtronik/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/swift3-cmzgbcrjozvlxvdgywzgbvuzmnqx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/JSQMessagesViewController -F /Users/Unitedtronik/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/swift3-cmzgbcrjozvlxvdgywzgbvuzmnqx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/JSQSystemSoundPlayer -F /Users/Unitedtronik/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/swift3-cmzgbcrjozvlxvdgywzgbvuzmnqx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/KissXML -F /Users/Unitedtronik/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/swift3-cmzgbcrjozvlxvdgywzgbvuzmnqx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/XMPPFramework -enable-testing -g -import-underlying-module -module-cache-path /Users/Unitedtronik/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache -D COCOAPODS -serialize-debugging-options -Xcc -I/Users/Unitedtronik/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/swift3-cmzgbcrjozvlxvdgywzgbvuzmnqx/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/xmpp-messenger-ios.build/swift-overrides.hmap -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/Unitedtronik/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/swift3-cmzgbcrjozvlxvdgywzgbvuzmnqx/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/xmpp-messenger-ios.build/xmpp_messenger_ios-generated-files.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/Unitedtronik/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/swift3-cmzgbcrjozvlxvdgywzgbvuzmnqx/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/xmpp-messenger-ios.build/xmpp_messenger_ios-own-target-headers.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/Unitedtronik/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/swift3-cmzgbcrjozvlxvdgywzgbvuzmnqx/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/xmpp-messenger-ios.build/xmpp_messenger_ios-all-non-framework-target-headers.hmap -Xcc -ivfsoverlay -Xcc /Users/Unitedtronik/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/swift3-cmzgbcrjozvlxvdgywzgbvuzmnqx/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/all-product-headers.yaml -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/Unitedtronik/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/swift3-cmzgbcrjozvlxvdgywzgbvuzmnqx/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/xmpp-messenger-ios.build/xmpp_messenger_ios-project-headers.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/Unitedtronik/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/swift3-cmzgbcrjozvlxvdgywzgbvuzmnqx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/xmpp-messenger-ios/include -Xcc -I/Users/Unitedtronik/Desktop/macProject/swift3v2/Pods/Headers/Private -Xcc -I/Users/Unitedtronik/Desktop/macProject/swift3v2/Pods/Headers/Public -Xcc -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator10.0.sdk/usr/include/libxml2 -Xcc -I/Users/Unitedtronik/Desktop/macProject/swift3v2/Pods/XMPPFramework/module -Xcc -I/Users/Unitedtronik/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/swift3-cmzgbcrjozvlxvdgywzgbvuzmnqx/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/xmpp-messenger-ios.build/DerivedSources/x86_64 -Xcc -I/Users/Unitedtronik/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/swift3-cmzgbcrjozvlxvdgywzgbvuzmnqx/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/xmpp-messenger-ios.build/DerivedSources -Xcc -DPOD_CONFIGURATION_DEBUG=1 -Xcc -DDEBUG=1 -Xcc -DCOCOAPODS=1 -Xcc -ivfsoverlay -Xcc /Users/Unitedtronik/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/swift3-cmzgbcrjozvlxvdgywzgbvuzmnqx/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/xmpp-messenger-ios.build/unextended-module-overlay.yaml -Xcc -working-directory/Users/Unitedtronik/Desktop/macProject/swift3v2/Pods -emit-module-doc-path /Users/Unitedtronik/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/swift3-cmzgbcrjozvlxvdgywzgbvuzmnqx/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/xmpp-messenger-ios.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/OneChat~partial.swiftdoc -Onone -module-name xmpp_messenger_ios -emit-module-path /Users/Unitedtronik/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/swift3-cmzgbcrjozvlxvdgywzgbvuzmnqx/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/xmpp-messenger-ios.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/OneChat~partial.swiftmodule -serialize-diagnostics-path /Users/Unitedtronik/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/swift3-cmzgbcrjozvlxvdgywzgbvuzmnqx/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/xmpp-messenger-ios.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/OneChat.dia -emit-dependencies-path /Users/Unitedtronik/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/swift3-cmzgbcrjozvlxvdgywzgbvuzmnqx/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/xmpp-messenger-ios.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/OneChat.d -emit-reference-dependencies-path /Users/Unitedtronik/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/swift3-cmzgbcrjozvlxvdgywzgbvuzmnqx/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/xmpp-messenger-ios.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/OneChat.swiftdeps -o /Users/Unitedtronik/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/swift3-cmzgbcrjozvlxvdgywzgbvuzmnqx/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/xmpp-messenger-ios.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/OneChat.o
>   /Users/Unitedtronik/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/swift3-cmzgbcrjozvlxvdgywzgbvuzmnqx/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/xmpp-messenger-ios.build/unextended-module.modulemap:2:19: error: umbrella header 'xmpp-messenger-ios-umbrella.h' not found
>     umbrella header "xmpp-messenger-ios-umbrella.h"
>                     ^
>   :0: error: could not build Objective-C module 'xmpp_messenger_ios'